# exporting collection contents to pdf in adf

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

```
  <af:commandButton text="Export to Excel"
                    binding="#{backingBeanScope.backing_ReportHealthCheck.cb1}"
                    id="cb1" partialTriggers="t1">
    <af:exportCollectionActionListener type="excelHTML" exportedId="t1"
                                       filename="ValidateResults.xlsx"
                                       title="ValidateResults"/>
  </af:commandButton>
```

I'm using this for exporting adf table with collection into Excel and is working fine.
But my requirement is exporting adf table with collection into pdf.If any one help on this issue.
I need to do this in a JSF page not in jsp page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This blog has a reusable component that will let you do this - http://adfwithejb.blogspot.com/2012/08/declarative-component-in-oracle-adf-to_28.html

Comment: yes it is working in Jsp perfectly.But I need to use it in JSF.